# Facing install4j: compilation failed. Reason: error during counter signing

Tags: jenkins, install4j, azure-node-sdk

We are facing below error

```
[install4j] Creating media file 'Windows':
[install4j] enter code here`Created media file output directory 

[install4j] Dec 18, 2021 2:53:08 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$1 run
[install4j] INFO: Created user preferences directory.
[install4j] Dec 18, 2021 2:53:08 PM java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences$2 run
[install4j] INFO: Created system preferences directory in java.home.
[install4j] install4j: compilation failed. Reason: error during counter signing
```

This issue is only when I trigger multiple CI jenkins jobs(min of 7) at a time and  have tried below options in jenkinsfile

```
-J-Dinstall4j.counterSignRetry=60
-J-Dinstall4j.connectTimeout=20000
-J-Dinstall4j.readTimeout=20000
```

Comment: Please compile with verbose mode to get a full stack trace

Comment: Thanks for your quick response ,and I have tried to compile in verbose mode using '-v',still not much information and performed as further analysis as "if we trigger 3 jobs at time ..jobs are successful and if we trigger more than 3 ,except 1st job all other  jobs are failing with mentioned signing error .Seems its performance issue ..please provide any workaround steps

Comment: I would really need the stack trace in order to be able to say anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally singer intermittent connectivity issue got resolved with JVM option
-Dinstall4j.connectTimeout=25000 and we are able run 15 jobs at a time without failure